# How can I select information in a tibble column that differs by row, based on a set of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

My apologies, as I don't even know what to title this problem!

But here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a tibble where every row is text dump of a document and each column is a different part of the document (i.e., title, index, chapter 1 name, chapter 1 text, chapter 2 name, chapter 2 text, etc.). In addition, I have columns that have been joined to this tibble that indicate which parts in each document need to be extracted. For example, for document 1, I might need chapter 3 text and chapter 4 text, where I may only need chapter 2 text for document 2, etc.

Here's an example, I'm starting with df1:

```
df1 <- as_tibble(data.frame(item = c('1','2','3','4'), 
                  selected_col1 = c('sec_3','sec_3','sec_4','sec_3'), 
                  selected_col2 = c('sec_4','sec_5',NA,'sec_6'),
                  selected_col3 = c('sec_5','sec_6',NA,NA),
                  selected_col4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  sec_1 = c('lorem ipsum1', 'lorem ipsum2','lorem ipsum3','lorem ipsum4'),
                  sec_2 = c('lorem ipsum5', 'lorem ipsum6','lorem ipsum7','lorem ipsum8'),
                  sec_3 = c('lorem ipsum9', 'lorem ipsum10','lorem ipsum11','lorem ipsum12'),
                  sec_4 = c('lorem ipsum13', 'lorem ipsum14','lorem ipsum15','lorem ipsum16'),
                  sec_5 = c('lorem ipsum17','lorem ipsum18','lorem ipsum19','lorem ipsum20'),
                  sec_6 = c('lorem ipsum21', 'lorem ipsum22','lorem ipsum23','lorem ipsum24'),
                  sec_7 = c('lorem ipsum25',' lorem ipsum26','lorem ipsum27','lorem ipsum28')))
```

and want to end up with df2:

```
df2 <- as_tibble(data.frame(item = c('1','2','3','4'), 
                            selected_col1 = c('sec_3','sec_3','sec_4','sec_3'), 
                            selected_col2 = c('sec_4','sec_5',NA,'sec_6'),
                            selected_col3 = c('sec_5','sec_6',NA,NA),
                            selected_col4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
                            sec_1 = c('lorem ipsum1', 'lorem ipsum2','lorem ipsum3','lorem ipsum4'),
                            sec_2 = c('lorem ipsum5', 'lorem ipsum6','lorem ipsum7','lorem ipsum8'),
                            sec_3 = c('lorem ipsum9', 'lorem ipsum10','lorem ipsum11','lorem ipsum12'),
                            sec_4 = c('lorem ipsum13', 'lorem ipsum14','lorem ipsum15','lorem ipsum16'),
                            sec_5 = c('lorem ipsum17','lorem ipsum18','lorem ipsum19','lorem ipsum20'),
                            sec_6 = c('lorem ipsum21', 'lorem ipsum22','lorem ipsum23','lorem ipsum24'),
                            sec_7 = c('lorem ipsum25',' lorem ipsum26','lorem ipsum27','lorem ipsum28'),
                            selection = c('lorem ipsum9 lorem ipsum13 lorem ipsum17','lorem ipsum10 lorem ipsum18 lorem ipsum22','lorem ipsum15','lorem ipsum12 lorem ipsum24')))
```

How would I tackle this? I know that in a dplyr / tidyverse world, I'll be mutating something, but that's about as far as I could figure it out. Unfortunately, this is much more complicated than my normal data wrangling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option by reshaping into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then `get` the value based on the column name in 'value' column, grouped by 'time', we `paste` the 'selection' column and do a `right_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('selected'), 
          values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
     rowwise %>%
     mutate(selection = get(value)) %>%
     group_by(item) %>%
     summarise(selection = str_c(selection,
              collapse = " "), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
     right_join(df1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 13
#  item  selection            selected_col1 selected_col2 selected_col3 selected_col4 sec_1    sec_2    sec_3   sec_4   sec_5   sec_6   sec_7   
#  <chr> <chr>                <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <lgl>         <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
#1 1     lorem ipsum9 lorem … sec_3         sec_4         sec_5         NA            lorem i… lorem i… lorem … lorem … lorem … lorem … "lorem …
#2 2     lorem ipsum10 lorem… sec_3         sec_5         sec_6         NA            lorem i… lorem i… lorem … lorem … lorem … lorem … " lorem…
#3 3     lorem ipsum15        sec_4         <NA>          <NA>          NA            lorem i… lorem i… lorem … lorem … lorem … lorem … "lorem …
#4 4     lorem ipsum12 lorem… sec_3         sec_6         <NA>          NA            lorem i… lorem i… lorem … lorem … lorem … lorem … "lorem …
```

Comment: Thank you! I had some of those pieces in different tries at this, but certainly not all of them together!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowwise` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(selection = paste(select(cur_data(), 
                           na.omit(c_across(starts_with('selected_col')))), 
                     collapse = ' ')) -> result

result$selection
#[1] "lorem ipsum9 lorem ipsum13 lorem ipsum17"  "lorem ipsum10 lorem ipsum18 lorem ipsum22"
#[3] "lorem ipsum15"                             "lorem ipsum12 lorem ipsum24"  

identical(result$selection, df2$selection)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In base R, we can use `apply` and apply the same logic.

```
selected_col <- grep('selected', names(df1))

df1$selection <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) 
                       paste(x[na.omit(x[selected_col])], collapse = ' '))
```